# JBoss 7.1.0 Security Domain: Multiple LDAPs--sequential, not failover

Tags: jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

So far, I am unable to find help for authenticating against multiple LDAP servers except where talking about failover.

We have an LDAP for internal users, and an LDAP for external users.  Suddenly, our app needs to be available to both internal users and external users.  How would I set this up?

Here is the current config for just internal users:

```
<security-domain name="dc-ldap-auth">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://dvldap-1.example.com:389"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
            <module-option name="bindDN" value="uid=someid,ou=People,ou=Intranet,o=example.com"/>
            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="somecred"/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=People,ou=Intranet,o=example.com"/>
            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Groups,ou=Intranet,o=example.com"/>
            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(uniqueMember={1})"/>
            <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
            <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you need simple configuration

Just use what JAAS offers. Add the two configurations to login module chain and set the `flag` on the first of them to `sufficient` value (look at [Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html) class for all the options and their description).

For optimal performance: The first configuration should be the one to which users authenticate more often.

```xml
<security-domain name="dc-ldap-auth">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="sufficient">
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url"
                           value="ldap://internal-ldap.my-company.example"/>
            <!-- add other options for the first LDAP server -->
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url"
                           value="ldap://external-ldap.my-company.example"/>
            <!-- add other options for the second LDAP server -->
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

### If you need great performance

If you are able to determine (from the loginname for instance) which LDAP you should search in, then I would suggest to implement your own login module. It can delegate the processing to `LdapExtLoginModule` instances.

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I needed.